# Is there a way to run async lambda synchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, async-await

Is there a way to run async lambda synchronously? It is not allowed to modify lambda expression, it must be leaved as is.

Copy/paste example(it's an abstraction):

```
var loopCnt = 1000000;

Action<List<int>> aslambda = async (l) =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    await Task.Run(() => { });
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCnt; i++) { l.Add(i); }
};

var lst = new List<int>();
aslambda(lst); //This runs asynchronously 
if (lst.Count < loopCnt-100) { ; }
```

### Solution:

It is **really** a dilemma for me to accept **one** answer. I have tried out the solution from *Stephen Cleary* with NuGet package - works brilliant and is broad applicable, but an answer from *dvorn* to the  question(as it's formulated ;)) is much easier.

Has *dvorn* changed the signature of lambda? No and Yes ;)

#### From MSDN:

> Note that lambda expressions in themselves do not have a type because
> the common type system has no intrinsic concept of "lambda
> expression." However, it is sometimes convenient to speak informally
> of the "type" of a lambda expression. In these cases the type refers
> to the delegate type or Expression type to which the lambda expression
> is converted.

So both receive **+1** and accepted answer by **Stephen Cleary**

Comment: aslmbda(lst).ToList() -> Wouldn't that stop deferred execution and force the list to be filled before returning to you?

Comment: The returned type of aslambda(..) is void.

Comment: `aslambda(lst).Wait();` ? and instead of `Thread.Sleep(100); await Task.Run(()=>{});` which has no sense just use `await Task.Delay(100);`

Comment: @ m.rogalski: The returned type of aslambda(..) is void! It is not allowed to modify lambda expression.

Comment: I didn't think that you _could_ track when an async void is done. Am I wrong?

Comment: In general your are right, but the question is whether it is possible to (run/impact from outside/extract body of) the async lambda such a way, that it runs synchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to run async [void] lambda synchronously?

Yes, but like all [sync-over-async hacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx), it's dangerous and won't work for all lambdas.

You must have a [custom `SynchronizationContext` to detect the completion of an `async void` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) (or lambda). This is non-trivial, but you can use my [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) (available in the NuGet package `Nito.AsyncEx.Context`):

```
AsyncContext.Run(() => aslambda(lst));
```

Comment: This is who I was waiting for. Going to try this one out myself.

Comment: The key is at the end of my [`SynchronizationContext` article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx): `async void` methods generate special code to notify the SyncCtx when they start and finish. UI SyncCtxs just ignore these notifications. These notifications are normally only used in legacy ASP.NET WebForms async event handlers, so ASP.NET can detect when the handlers are all finished and the response is ready to be sent to the client.

Comment: Thank you for giving the direction. I will try it out. It would be nice, if you could post a code sample(not with NuGet package).

Comment: @Rekshino: No, it's too much code. You can [check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context), though.

Comment: @StephenCleary There is a much easier approach to the problem (at least as it is formulated).

Comment: @dvorn: You changed the signature of the lambda, which the op specifically said isn't possible.

Comment: @StephenCleary Nope.  He said "lambda expression".  This is the part to right of "=".

Comment: @StephenCleary This has a broader meaning: assigning async lambda to Action make sense only when dealing with external historical APIs using Actions.  If the code is all yours, this should be considered bad practice which should be avoided, because it creates problem which you brilliantly demonstrated how to solve.  But in first place, you need not create such problems for yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately it is incompatible with version 4.5 .2 . Is there any way to use the same in version 4.5.2??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: Yes; older platforms are supported with `Nito.AsyncEx` v4.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution:  You cannot change the lambda, but you may change the type of local variable it is assigned to.  Note that native type of async lambda is not Action but Func<Task>.

```
...
Func<List<int>, Task> aslambda = async (l) =>
...
...
aslambda(lst).Wait();
...
```