# Wait for finish all async methods inside an Async lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, lambda

I have a method like below

```
internal static ProgressDialogResult Execute(Window owner, string label, Action operation, ProgressDialogSettings settings)
{
    return ExecuteInternal(owner, label, (object)operation, settings);
}
```

Which is used to display a progress bar based on task completions. 
I am calling the above method like below

```
int count = soilData.Count;

var result = ProgressDialog.Execute(this, "Loading data", async () => {
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i = i + 1000)
      {
         await soilDataMigration.MigrateSoilData(soilData.GetRange(i, i + 1000 >= count ? count - i : 1000));    
      }
   }, ProgressDialogSettings.WithSubLabel);

if (result.OperationFailed)
   MessageBox.Show("Soil data upload failed failed.");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Soil data successfully executed.");
soilData.Clear();
```

But when I try to execute the same it is suddenly comes out of the lambda and start executing if statement. 
But my expected behavior is the control goes out of this lambda only when all my async operations are completed inside loop .

I have checked this question in stackoverflow 
                            [Is there a way to run async lambda synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369832/is-there-a-way-to-run-async-lambda-synchronously)

But unfortunately that package is incompatible with .net version 4.5.2

Can someone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Instead of an `Action` why not `Func<Task>` and await it?

Comment: @DavidG I have created the same, but not sure how can i use it here , can you please provide me a sample code ?

Comment: Either change your whole API to work with `async...await` OR change the code you pass to lambda, e.g. `soilDataMigration.MigrateSoilData(soilData.GetRange(i, i + 1000 >= count ? count - i : 1000)).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: @zaitsman shows an error like cannot await void when i try to use the code provided by you

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV remove `await` obviously...

Comment: @zaitsman  perfect ... Can you please post it as an answer then i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically you have two options:
1) refactor all of the calls to be `async..await` compatible, e.g.

```
internal static async System.Threading.Task<ProgressDialogResult> Execute(Window owner, string label, Func<System.Threading.Task> operation, ProgressDialogSettings settings)
{
    return await ExecuteInternal(owner, label, (object)operation, settings);
}

internal static async System.Threading.Task<ProgressDialogResult> ExecuteInternal(Window owner, string label, Func<System.Threading.Task> operation, ProgressDialogSettings settings)
{
    // do whatever
    await operation();
    return //whatever;
}
```

Then consume it like so:

```
int count = soilData.Count;

var result = await ProgressDialog.Execute(this, "Loading data", async () => {
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i = i + 1000)
      {
         await soilDataMigration.MigrateSoilData(soilData.GetRange(i, i + 1000 >= count ? count - i : 1000));    
      }
   }, ProgressDialogSettings.WithSubLabel);

if (result.OperationFailed)
   MessageBox.Show("Soil data upload failed failed.");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Soil data successfully executed.");
soilData.Clear();
```

and
2) just change the `await` method you're passing to be
`soilDataMigration.MigrateSoilData(soilData.GetRange(i, i + 1000 >= count ? count - i : 1000)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

In general, option 1) is better as it clearly denotes intent and harmonizes the code you have. Option 2) is more a workaround.